# expecting primary-expression before 'char'

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void reverse(char*);

void reverse(char* str) 
{
    char * end = str;
    char tmp; 
    if (str) {
        while (*end) {
            ++end;
        }
     }
     --end;
     while (str < end) {
         tmp = *str;
         *str++ = *end;
         *end-- = tmp;
     }
}

int main {
   char * string;
   string = "Hello";
   reverse(string);
   std::cout << string;
   return 0; 
}
```

Hello. I am trying to test this simple function and get the error "expecting primary expression before 'char'" on the line where I declare the variable string as a char pointer. Excuse my being a neophyte and probably making additional errors. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You have not included parens and arguments in the definition of `main`.

Comment: You also have undefined behavior: While C allows assigning a literal string to a `char*` - you cannot modify it. You need to allocate a buffer (either on the stack or free store) and copy the literal to it before you can safely modify it.  On some architectures, you may run into access violations as literals are generally in read-only memory.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the argument list for main, which has two allowable values:

```
int main(void)  // Option 1
{
    // The 'void' is optional; in C++, it's equivalent to "int main()", but there
    // is a difference in plain C
    ...
}

// OR

int main(int argc, char *argv[])  // Option 2
{
    // The names of the variables argc and argv can of course be changed; argv
    // can also be declared as char**
    ...
}
```

You also have a semantic problem, which is that string literals like like `"Hello"` are non-modifiable.  There is a deprecated conversion from `const char[]` to `char*`, but that should be avoided, and your compiler should warn you about it if you enable warnings.  If you attempt to run the code, you will get a segmentation fault or access violation.

To fix that, you should declare your `string` variable as a modifiable array, not a pointer:

```
char string[] = "Hello";
```

Comment: Note that in the first version, `void` is not needed.